# Object property doesn't return value after arithmentic operation is performed

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Plain an simple, I have this small app, and it breaks when I call the applyDamage function in the player object. When I tried debugging, and got the type of, it says it's a number. Yet, when I run it's not computing properly past the first iteration because it's throwing the NaN error. I really would appreciate your help if any. I've tried many different simple tricks, so please only advanced responses if you have time to review my code.

Nevertheless,

Thank you in advance!

```
var gameOver = function(){
    console.log("Game Over");
  return 0;
};

var youWin = function(arrPlayersAlive){
  console.log("\nCongratulations, you have defeated Scarlet Byte.\n");
  console.log("Players Alive:");
  console.log("==============");
  for(var x = 0; x < arrPlayersAlive.length; x++){
    console.log(arrPlayersAlive[x].name);
  }
};

var rndNumbGen = function(min, max){
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

var fight = function(arrActivePlayers, arrActiveMinion){
    var playersAlive = arrActivePlayers.length;
  var minionsAlive = arrActiveMinion.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < arrActivePlayers.length; i++){
    var weapon = new Weapon(arrActivePlayers[i].myWeapon);
    while(arrActivePlayers[i].isAlive() === true){
      for(var x = 0; x < arrActiveMinion.length; x++){
        while(arrActiveMinion[x].isAlive() === true){
          weapon.attack(arrActivePlayers[i], arrActiveMinion[x]);
        }
        if(arrActiveMinion[x].isAlive() === false){
            minionsAlive = minionsAlive - 1;
          if(minionsAlive === 0){ youWin(arrActivePlayers); }
        }
      }
    }
    if(arrActivePlayers[i].isAlive() === false){
        playersAlive = playersAlive - 1;
      if(playersAlive === 0){ gameOver(); }
    }
  }
};

function Player(strName, arrWeapons){
    this.name = strName;
  this.health = parseInt(10);
  this.strength = parseInt(2);
  this.weapons = arrWeapons;
  this.myWeapon = "unarmed";
  this.applyDamage = function(intDamage){
    this.health -= parseInt(intDamage);
    console.log(this.name + " has sustained " + intDamage + " amount of damage. Remainig health " + this.health);
  };
  this.isAlive = function(){
    if(this.health <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
  };
  this.attackWith = function(){
    this.myWeapon = this.weapons[rndNumbGen(0,7)];
  };
}

function Minion(){
  this.name = "Minion";
  this.health = parseInt(5);
  this.strength = parseInt(2);
  this.applyDamage = function(intDamage){
    this.health = this.health - parseInt(intDamage);
    console.log(this.name + " has sustained " + intDamage + " amount of damage.");
  };
  this.isAlive = function(){
    if(this.health <= 0){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  };
  this.attack = function(objPlayer){
    objPlayer.applyDamage(this.strength);
  };
}

function Weapon(strName){
    this.name = strName;
  this.damage = rndNumbGen(1,5);
  this.attack = function(objPlayer, objMinion){
    objMinion.applyDamage(objPlayer.strength);
    if(objMinion.isAlive() === true){
        objPlayer.applyDamage(objMinion.attack(objPlayer));
    }
  };
}

function Game(){
    this.players = [];
  this.minion = [];
  this.createMinions = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        this.minion[i] = new Minion();
    }
  };
  this.createPlayers = function(){
    var weaponsCache = ["Over Gold", "Kunai", "Flame Thrower", "BuzzBomb", "God_Scythe", "Ankle Biting Chihuahua Launcher", "Mini Black Hole", "Small Pox Blanket"];
      var playerNames = ["Loki_Blacksteel", "Naruto", "CERN", "Harambe", "Kung Fu Joe"];
    for(var n = 0; n < playerNames.length; n++){
        this.players[n] = new Player(playerNames[n], weaponsCache);
    }
  };
  this.play = function(){
    console.log("Simulating Battle\n");
    this.createMinions();
    this.createPlayers();
    fight(this.players, this.minion);
  };
}

var myGame = new Game();
myGame.play();
```

Comment: ```NaN```'s type IS number. If you go to console and type ```typeof NaN```, you will get ```'number'```. Whatever your problem is, it might be occurring before it gets to that method

Comment: Hi - your code is not really clean (Clean Code in the sense of Robert C. Martin). You could read some Micheal Feathers (Refatoring Legacy Code) and the aformentioned Clean Code - that woud make your Code far better.

- I would suggest not to nest while, for and ifs so deeply - this is really unreadable.

- Do not use shortenings for names

- Use "extract method" for small snippets

- Make use of JavaScript Modules

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is that in your weapon class you have

`objPlayer.applyDamage(objMinion.attack(objPlayer));`

but `applyDamage()` takes an integer and your `attack()` function doesn't return anything

You are trying to call `parseInt` inside your `applyDamage` method but you are passing it an undefined value, which explains the NaN error.

Hope thats helps.

```js
console.log(parseInt(undefined))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `applyDamage` function twice
First:

```
objPlayer.applyDamage(objMinion.attack(objPlayer));
```

Second: 
`objMinion.attack(objPlayer)` calls apply damage in its body

```
 this.attack = function(objPlayer){
    objPlayer.applyDamage(this.strength);
 };
```

The first one calls `applyDamage` with undefined (if function has no return state it returns undefined) value, the second one with 2.  You can try writing `objMinion.attack(objPlayer));` instead of `objPlayer.applyDamage(objMinion.attack(objPlayer));`